# Makefile doesn't use variables

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am refactoring [my personal libc](https://github.com/Seluj78/libft) and I need to redo my makefile. So far so good, But suddenly, the variables aren't included in the commands executed.

Here's the trouble so far:

```
➜  libft git:(master) ✗ make
clang    -c -o srcs/core/ft_add_to_array.o srcs/core/ft_add_to_array.c
srcs/core/ft_add_to_array.c:13:10: fatal error: 'core/core.h' file not found #include <core/core.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'srcs/core/ft_add_to_array.o' failed
make: *** [srcs/core/ft_add_to_array.o] Error 1
```

Which i suppose come from this line of [my makefile](https://pastebin.com/iftjg59Y) :

```
%.o:$(SRC_PATH)/%.c
      $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INC) -o $@ -c $<
```

So what i've come up so far is that the FLAGS and INC variables are simply not included... Any ideas why ?

Comment: Your guess for what's happening can't be right. The fact that you get `-c -o srcs/.../file.o srcs/.../file.c` when your `Makefile` specifies `-o file.o -c srcs/.../file.c` shows that your rule is not being used. Instead, some built-in rule (which doesn't use `FLAGS` or `INC`) is used.

Comment: In that case, what should I do ? This rule worked for me in the past, and all of a sudden it doesn't anymore

Comment: The underlying problem may be that it's attempting to build `srcs/core/ft_add_to_array.o` (not covered by your rule) rather than `ft_add_to_array.o` (which is) or `./obj/core/ft_add_to_array.o` (which seems to be the one you actually want).

Comment: Presumably, to concur with the previous comment, the file you are compiling does not match the pattern `$(SRC_PATH)/%.c`. We don't know what `SRC_PATH` is set to, so we have to speculate about the parts we can't see.

Comment: I see what you guys mean, but I have no idea about how to fix it... i've tried changing `$(SRC_PATH)/%.c` but nothing here

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution

I've removed the `addsuffix` part and added `srcs/` to each line of the sources i've declared manually and it compiled fine !

[Here's the makefile after my modifications](https://pastebin.com/FTscS3Pq)

Thanks guys